# Is there an easy way to close multiple handles?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, handles

Is there a way to close multiple handles to threads in C++ without having to close them individually?  I have a few threads with handles that I have stored in an array so I can use `WaitForMultipleObjects()` before closing them.  I know I could call `CloseHandle` on each handle in the array (either by loop or just one-by-one), but I was wondering if there was a simple way to close them all.  Such as perhaps running `CloseHandle` on the array itself (if that would work)?  Or does there exist a method along the lines of `CloseMultipleHandles()`?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect it's rather a winapi question than c++

Comment: Just close (join) each thread one by one (how often are you doing it!?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Loop and CloseHandle is the easiest solution. (Not that it's extremely difficult to implement...).

But then you can always create a CloseAllHandles function which takes an array of handles to close them...

Comment: Not the easiest, the only

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There is no easier either ;-) So it is the easiest *and* the only.